# How to call a function of AngularJS directive when click anywhere on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to call close() function on click anywhere in page,but didn't work. I have written like:

```
var liveSearch = function () {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        myData: '=',
        ngModel: '='
    },
    templateUrl: "/js/app/common/template/livesearch.html",
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

        var close = function() {
            $scope.status = "close";
        };

        $scope.open = function () {
            $scope.status = "open";
        };

        $(document).on('click',function(){
            close();
        });
    }
};
app.directive("liveSearch", liveSearch);
```

Please help to solve this problem.

**Edited**

```
<div live-search my-data="data" ng-model="typeId" ></div>
```

Comment: Can you share, how you are using this directive ??

Comment: Please look at the edited section

Answer (score 1):

Try using this clickElsewhere directive for detecting click anywhere outside that DOM object.

```
directive('clickElsewhere', function($parse, $rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: function($element, attr) {
                var fn;
                fn = $parse(attr['clickElsewhere']);
                return function(scope, element) {
                    var offEvent;
                    offEvent = $rootScope.$on('click', function(event, target) {
                        if (element.find($(target)).length || element.is($(target))) {
                            return;
                        }
                        return scope.$apply(function() {
                            return fn(scope);
                        });
                    });
                    return scope.$on('$destroy', offEvent);
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

You can use it like so in your template:

```
<div live-search my-data="data" ng-model="typeId" click-else-where="close()"></div>
```

Comment: It work only textbox keydown event,not click event. This directive created for live search and when I try type for searching anything in textbox close() function call.

Comment: provided directive work on click - as it's stated in your question and in its code ```$rootScope.$on('click',...```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an `click` handler inside `link`

```
link:function($scope, element, attrs)){
    $scope.close = function(){
  // Rest of the code
   }       
    $('body').on('click',function(event){
      $scope.close();
      })
   }
```